# Display and update multiple form fields on selecting a value from a dropdown in a jsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working in Spring MVC 3.0. I have a page with a drop-down, say the master drop-down, and multiple fields that are dependent on the value of the drop-down. When the value of the drop-down is selected, I want to query the database and get around 12 field values and a list and display these fields on the JSP. Also, there are 2 more drop-downs whose list of values depends on the master drop-down.

I have thought of the following approaches:
1. Making a AJAX call and displaying the 12 fields through AJAX. And making 2 more AJAX calls to get the values of the remaining 2 drop downs.
2. Making an AJAX call setting a bean object and then including another view containing the 12 fields. And making 2 more AJAX calls to get the values of the remaining drop down. But I am not sure on how to include/render a view through AJAX in Spring MVC.
3. Having a hidden div containing all the dependent fields and using AJAX to return the values of the fields. But I am not sure on how to return multiple values using AJAX and then using them to update existing fields.

Which approach should I follow or if there is some other way this can be handled?

I am fairly new to Spring MVC and would appreciate any help with a code snippet on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think 1 option is good. Where are you stuck?

Comment: you can use jquery to render JSON response from your controllers. Jquery provides very good support for this. you need to add `@ResponseBody` to your controller methods, spring will automatically take care to return JSON if you have 'Jackson' added to your classpath.

Comment: @varun: Could you provide some code snippet or a link demonstrating the same

Comment: @Aniket: The 1st approach requires me to replace the existing div containing all the fields with the ones from the AJAX request. I am not sure how to update the values of form fields in the AJAX request with the value set in the controller. Could you help me with that

Comment: try these: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-mvc-ajax-and-json-part-1-setting-the-scene.html   http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-mvc-ajax-and-json-part-2-the-server-side-code.html http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/spring-mvc-ajax-and-json-part-3-the-client-side-code.html

Comment: Your div and fields are not visible, are they invisible. For solving problem you need to post the code snippet where you have stuck or some code that is helpful for understanding problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your controller action (the one you call via ajax) return a partial view instead of json. The partial view would contain your dependent dropdowns/etc and use a view model populated by the controller.  Then your ajax callback can just replace your hidden div with the ajax response (which would be the partial view containing the updated data).

Alternatively, if you want to return json from the controller, you can parse it on the ajax callback and use jquery like `$(selector).val(yourParsedValue)` to set the values of specific fields.

Comment: I have thought of this approach, but am not sure how to include the partial view through ajax response and how to update the values in the  partial view. Could you help me with that